# Saving an image file with node fs.createWriteStream(path)?

Tags: node.js, axios, facebook-javascript-sdk

Attempting to execute the [code from this article](https://futurestud.io/tutorials/download-files-images-with-axios-in-node-js) and getting:

```
Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/home/ole/Temp/image/images/code.jpg'
Emitted 'error' event at:
    at internal/fs/streams.js:289:12
    at FSReqCallback.oncomplete (fs.js:153:23) {
  errno: -2,
  code: 'ENOENT',
  syscall: 'open',
  path: '/home/ole/Temp/image/images/code.jpg'
```

How do we get `fs.createWriteStream(path)` to create the file it's trying to write?

This is the code that is attempting to write the image:

```
'use strict'

const Fs = require('fs')  
const Path = require('path')  
const Axios = require('axios')

async function downloadImage () {  
    const url = 'https://unsplash.com/photos/AaEQmoufHLk/download?force=true'
    const path = Path.resolve(__dirname, 'images', 'code.jpg')
    const writer = Fs.createWriteStream(path)

    const response = await Axios({
      url,
      method: 'GET',
      responseType: 'stream'
    })

    response.data.pipe(writer)

    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      writer.on('finish', resolve)
      writer.on('error', reject)
    })
  }

  downloadImage()
```

Comment: That's probably because this directory `'/home/ole/Temp/image/images` doesn't exist.  `fs.createWriteStream()` won't create the directory for you.  It will create the file, but not the directory.

Comment: Hehe - Good catch - Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's probably because this directory `/home/ole/Temp/image/images` doesn't exist or you don't have proper permissions for it.

`fs.createWriteStream()` won't create the directory for you. It will create the file, but not the directory.